# Server Rack setup, correct?

Tags: hardware, rack

I plan to build my server inside a rack.
It is pretty simple but not cheap so I wanted to know if everything fits?

Parts:
-https://www.amazon.de/Serverschrank-stehende-Schrank-Traglast-RAL7035/dp/B019E8KBI4/ref=pd_sbs_147_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=P1TXQ5AXDK0GV4JJC39P

-https://www.amazon.de/Realpower-RPS19-450-Geh%C3%A4use-Netzteil-schwarz/dp/B0030UQZ9M/ref=sr_1_3?s=musical-instruments&ie=UTF8&qid=1500072943&sr=8-3&keywords=server+rack+geh%C3%A4use

A very simple question but I am not an expert and not want to buy the wrong things and waste my money!

Comment: 19" rack is a standard, so there shouldn't be any issues. However, this is a topic you should discuss with the vendor, instead. That's why it's marked as off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These two components should fit together but this is not a standard depth (distance front to back) server rack.  This is the size rack that is normally used for communications gear like network switches and patch panels.  If you later buy a full (standard) length server, it will not fit in this rack.
You can read about the standard dimensions of a server rack at this link:
http://www.42u.com/42U-cabinets.htm
Have fun

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick reply.
Can you recommend me a suitable?